# Modifying just the path part of a Hyperlink's NavigateUrl in C#

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I would like to modify the `NavigateUrl` property of a `Hyperlink` control.  I need to preserve the querystring but change the path of the hyperlink's URL.

Something along these lines:

```
var control = (Hyperlink) somecontrol;

// e.g., control.NavigateUrl == "http://www.example.com/path/to/file?query=xyz"

var uri = new Uri(control.NavigateUrl);
uri.AbsolutePath = "/new/absolute/path";

control.NavigateUrl = uri.ToString();

// control.NavigateUrl == "http://www.example.com/new/absolute/path?query=xyz"
```

`Uri.AbsolutePath` is read-only ([no setter defined](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.absolutepath%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)), though, so this solution won't work.

How would I change just the path of a `Hyperlink`'s `NavigateUrl` property while leaving the querystring, hostname and schema parts intact?

Comment: Incidentally, I am investigating this as a possible workaround for a problem described in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267020/datapager-controls-use-sitecore-layout-url-instead-of-item-url).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find the [UriBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uribuilder.aspx) class useful:

```
var oldUrl = "http://www.example.com/path/to/file?query=xyz";
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(oldUrl);
uriBuilder.Path = "new/absolute/path";
var newUrl = uriBuilder.ToString();
```

or to make it a little more generic:

```
public string ChangePath(string url, string newPath)
{
    var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(url);
    uriBuilder.Path = newPath;
    return uriBuilder.ToString();
}
```

and then:

```
var control = (Hyperlink) somecontrol;
control.NavigateUrl = ChangePath(control.NavigateUrl, "new/absolute/path");
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it!  I ended up having to use uriBuilder.Uri.PathAndQuery instead of uriBuilder.ToString() though.  See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267020/datapager-controls-use-sitecore-layout-url-instead-of-item-url/5304861#5304861) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the String at the first question mark and then concatenate the new domain with that.